# EvoSuite is not generating any tests

Tags: java, junit, evosuite

I installed the "EvoSuite" plugin for automatic JUnit test generation in IntelliJ and I tried some example codes / projects. Non of these projects would make EvoSuite to generate any tests at all.

Only a default test is being generated with an empty body. Is that it? Or am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated. Maybe from someone who is already using EvoSuite?

I receive the following error log by the way:

```
> projectCP target/classes
* EvoSuite 1.0.6
* Going to generate test cases for class: example.Foo
* Starting client
* Connecting to master process on port 6791
* Analyzing classpath:
  - target/classes
* Finished analyzing classpath
* Generating tests for class example.Foo
* Test criteria:
  - Line Coverage
  - Branch Coverage
  - Exception
  - Mutation testing (weak)
  - Method-Output Coverage
  - Top-Level Method Coverage
  - No-Exception Top-Level Method Coverage
  - Context Branch Coverage
* Setting up search algorithm for whole suite generation
* Total number of test goals:
  - Line 6
  - Branch 6
  - Exception 0
  - MutationFactory 33
  - Output 4
  - Method 4
  - MethodNoException 4
  - CBranchFitnessFactory 6
* Using seed 1542038670338
* Starting evolution
[Progress:>                             1%] [Cov:===================================100%]
* Search finished after 2s and 0 generations, 5090 statements, best individual has fitness: 1.0
* Minimizing test suite
* Going to analyze the coverage criteria
* Coverage analysis for criterion LINE
* Coverage of criterion LINE: 100%
* Total number of goals: 6
* Number of covered goals: 6
* Coverage analysis for criterion BRANCH
* Coverage of criterion BRANCH: 100%
* Total number of goals: 6
* Number of covered goals: 6
* Coverage analysis for criterion EXCEPTION
* Coverage of criterion EXCEPTION: 100% (no goals)
* Coverage analysis for criterion WEAKMUTATION
* Coverage of criterion WEAKMUTATION: 100%
* Total number of goals: 33
* Number of covered goals: 33
* Coverage analysis for criterion OUTPUT
* Coverage of criterion OUTPUT: 100%
* Total number of goals: 4
* Number of covered goals: 4
* Coverage analysis for criterion METHOD
* Coverage of criterion METHOD: 100%
* Total number of goals: 4
* Number of covered goals: 4
* Coverage analysis for criterion METHODNOEXCEPTION
* Coverage of criterion METHODNOEXCEPTION: 100%
* Total number of goals: 4
* Number of covered goals: 4
* Coverage analysis for criterion CBRANCH
* Coverage of criterion CBRANCH: 100%
* Total number of goals: 6
* Number of covered goals: 6
* Generated 6 tests with total length 17
* Resulting test suite's coverage: 100% (average coverage for all fitness functions)
* Generating assertions
* Resulting test suite's mutation score: 100%
* Compiling and checking tests
[MASTER] 17:04:36.738 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
Stack trace:
java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:807)
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:886)
javax.swing.RepaintManager.<clinit>(RepaintManager.java:238)
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_6_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_6_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> [MASTER] 17:04:36.865 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Could not initialize class javax.swing.RepaintManager
Stack trace:
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_7_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_7_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> [MASTER] 17:04:36.969 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Could not initialize class javax.swing.RepaintManager
Stack trace:
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_8_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_8_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> [MASTER] 17:04:37.076 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Could not initialize class javax.swing.RepaintManager
Stack trace:
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_9_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_9_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> [MASTER] 17:04:37.174 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Could not initialize class javax.swing.RepaintManager
Stack trace:
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_10_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_10_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> [MASTER] 17:04:37.286 [logback-2] ERROR JUnitAnalyzer - Issue in scaffolding of the test suite: Could not initialize class javax.swing.RepaintManager
Stack trace:
javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3311)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(AbstractButton.java:1784)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:134)
javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:91)
org.evosuite.runtime.GuiSupport.initialize(GuiSupport.java:96)
example.Foo_11_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.initEvoSuiteFramework(Foo_11_tmp__ESTest_scaffolding.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runJUnitOnCurrentProcess(JUnitAnalyzer.java:306)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.runTests(JUnitAnalyzer.java:276)
org.evosuite.junit.JUnitAnalyzer.handleTestsThatAreUnstable(JUnitAnalyzer.java:178)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.compileAndCheckTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:594)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.postProcessTests(TestSuiteGenerator.java:533)
org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:238)
org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:145)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> * Writing JUnit test case 'Foo_ESTest' to evosuite-tests
> * Done!

> * Computation finished
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It was solved issue by opening `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` and commenting out the following line:

```
assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

as suggested [here](https://solveme.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/java-awt-awterror-assistive-technology-not-found-org-gnome-accessibility-atkwrapper-when-running-jasper-reports/).